# vue transition-group key on nested v-for

Tags: html, vue.js

I am attempting to apply vue transitions to the `v-design-row` component only. I am using the `transition-group` to handle changes within the data object, but I have 3 rows inside the `v-for`. Its not an issue to include keys to the other rows to prevent this warnining:

> [Vue warn]:  children must be keyed:

I can see that because one the child elements is a nested `v-for` loop, that once I add the key to the `v-catagory-row` component this error displays:

> TypeError: el.getAttribute is not a function

- Is there not a way to omit a single child element from the `transition-group`?
- Can anyone suggest how I can structure this to achieve the desired results?

**component.vue**

```
    <template>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Order</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        </thead>
        <transition-group name="fade" tag="tbody">
            <template v-for="design in data">
                <v-catagory-row @update="updateValue" v-for="catagory in design.catagories" :catagory="catagory" :catagoryCheck="catagoryCheck" :key="design.id"></v-catagory-row>
                <v-design-row @delete="deleteDesign" :design="design" :key="design.id"></v-design-row>
                <v-description-row :design="design" :key="design.id"></v-description-row>
            </template>
        </transition-group>
    </table>
   </template>
```